# Remix: gas required exceeds allowance when calling IERC20 transferFrom

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20

When I called fransferFrom by using erc20 interface (IERC20), an error says "gas required exceeds allowance (10000000) or always failing transaction".

I made allowance for the contract beforehand.

This is the contract that call transferFrom.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.7;

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract TokenSale {

    address public token_address;

    constructor(address _token_address) public {
        token_address = _token_address;
    }
    
    function sendEtherFromDeposit(address _token_supplyer) public returns(bool success) { 
        require(IERC20(token_address).allowance(_token_supplyer, address(this)) >= 10000, "insufficient allowance amount");
        IERC20(token_address).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, 1000);
        success = true;
    }
    
}
```

Are there any problem of my code?
Could you give me any advise, please?

Comment: Did you call `approve` beforehand?

Comment: BTW, please fix your code. There is no such variable `icb_address`. Same goes for `_icb_supplyer`. There is also no local variable `_token_address` in the constructor. On top of all of that, the opening statement of your question makes no sense descriptive-wise. This question is in poor condition!

Comment: Sorry for my poor English,, I fixed my contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently trying to send tokens from the contract itself, rather than from `_token_supplyer` (which I assume is what you intended to do). The first parameter of `transferFrom` specifies the address to send the tokens for, so if you set it to `address(this)`, the token tries to send tokens from the contract, but fails because you didn't set the allowance or the contract doesn't have enough balance.

It will work if you specify `_token_supplyer` as first parameter instead:

```
IERC20(token_address).transferFrom(_token_supplyer, msg.sender, 1000);
```

The token contract can check if `_token_supplyer` has allowed the contract to spend tokens by checking `msg.sender`. You don't need to specify the contract address itself in `transferFrom`.